# Is there any 3d software which can give transformation matrix of the scene elements

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, 3d

I have a 3D model which has position, uv, normal, indices info. I need to place it in a scene and render it in a renderer which expects camera, light, geomtery and all their transformation. I have some how displayed a model successfully by hardcoding the camera, light properties with the geometry info I already have. I figured out the transformations for the camera and light necessary to fit the model in the view and lit it properly by trial and error method. But that is cumbersome and specific to this particular geometry. I need to hard code some transformation for camera ,light and 3D geometries to get a satifactory view. Is there any 3D software from where I can get the transformation matrices of the light, camera and geometries to use those values in my program?

Comment: What file format are your models in?  You have a tag that says `3dsmax`, if it's that then all the transformation matrices are in the 3ds/fbx files...

Comment: No They are custom file formats having only geom info...

Comment: Then you have lost the information you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the ideas! I atlast found that simple utiltiy I was looking for @ : http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_transform.html

http://www.songho.ca/opengl/files/matrixModelView.zip
http://www.songho.ca/opengl/files/matrixProjection.zip

Answer (score 0):

Any 3D software saves all the necessary transformation matrices in the scene files - what else should it do? Guess where to place the camera?

What you should try is this approach:

1. Convert your custom file format into something your 3D software of choice can read and render.
2. Place camera and lights
3. Save the new scene
4. Convert the scene file into text or something where you can read the few matrices that you care about

I suggest to try [Blender](http://www.blender.org/) because it uses the Python scripting language ([docs](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_61_4/)) - that will allow you to completely automate the whole process.

Comment: Its quite reasonable ,I understand there is no shortcut. But converting to the format that blender understands is not part of the scope of the project. I was greedy to steal the transformation matrices alone from the 3D software by approximating the geometry with a cube and positoning camera and lights accordingly.

Comment: Create a scene in blender using a cube and some lights and then use a python script to print the transformation matrices of all objects in the scene (plus probably some additional transformation to get them in a form which you can really use).